# OrmLite Code-First approach keeping existing database data?

Tags: c#, orm, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying Code-First approach of ServiceStack.OrmLite that will auto generate db structure.

However, I find that the db structure will be re-generated again when I change the code structure (and erasing all my existing data as well).

Actually, is it possible to keep the existing data when I redo the Code-First ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy all data to a temp table and create the new one, after that just copy the data from temp table to the new table, than you will keep the data after migration.

Please find the detail information in [here](https://www.mysharings.com/coderblog/use-code-first-migration-servicestack-ormlite/). :)